# What to backfill with in type-column on polymorphic table?

Tags: laravel

I am changing my `File`-model to go from `one to many` to be a `one to many polymorphic` relation. Before only my `User`-model could have a file but now my model `Guest` will also be able to have a file.

So before I had a column in the file table named `user_id` I have renamed that one following the pattern here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

So it is now named `fileable_id`.

In addition to the renaming I have added a column named `fileable_type`. I now want to backfill that column so everything existing points on the `User`-model. **What should I write in that column?**

I have tried `App\User` and `User` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App\User` should be correct if that is how you have your User model namespaced. The polymorphich relationships use the `getMorphClass()` method on the Eloquent model. You can verify this by doing:

```
$u = new User();
dd($u->getMorphClass());
```

If you have not created a [custom polymorphic type](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types) for the User model, then `getMorphClass()` should be equivalent to `User::class`.